# div.innerHTML and div.innerText behaving differently when appending

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net web app that tails a log file. I want to insert new log entries in the bottom of a div and have it scroll updawards. If I use the following line, it works fine

```
textDiv.innerText += value.toString() + "\r\n";
```

However, If I use the following, It adds new entries to the top, not the bottom.

```
textDiv.innerHTML += value.toString() + "\r\n";
```

I need to be able to use innerHTML so that I can parse entries into spans, colour them etc. I have the div styling as follows

```
.textdiv {
    height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

See image blow of the div in action. Can anyone help me to correct the behaviour of textDiv.innerHTML such that new entries into the div are added to the bottom not the top.  Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Html will be appended to the bottom of textdiv, but displayed at the top due to [flex-direction: column-reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: You should really create a new element and append (or prepend) it to `.textDiv` instead of adding directly to `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I came up with, should anyone else find it useful is as follows. I changed my css to get rid of flex (no longer use flex-direction: column-reverse;) as follows

```
.textdiv {
    height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and I changed my js to read as follows

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (value) => {

    var line = value.toString();
    $("#textdiv").append($(line));

    // Keep scrolling to the bottom of the div    
    var element = document.getElementById("textdiv");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;    
});
```

Seems to work well now.